# How to change application icon as per switch value in Android programmatically

Tags: android

I have a switch in my application. If the switch is `on` i want to set one different icon. If the switch is `off` i have to set the other icon.

I am trying like this

```
    tButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {

            if (isChecked)
            {
                tvStateofToggleButton.setText("ON");
            getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
                        new ComponentName("com.samir", "com.samir.MainActivity-Red"), 
                            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
            } else
            {
                tvStateofToggleButton.setText("OFF");
                getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
                   new ComponentName("com.samir", "com.samir.MainActivity-Blue"), 
                          PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
            }

        }
    });
```

Manifest is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.samir"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity-alias
        android:name=".MainActivity-Red"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/red"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:targetActivity=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
    <activity-alias
        android:name=".MainActivity-Blue"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/blue"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:targetActivity=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
</application>

</manifest>
```

The console shows as below

```
       [2013-11-09 13:03:40 - Android Switch Button] ActivityManager: Error type 3
       [2013-11-09 13:03:40 - Android Switch Button] ActivityManager: Error: Activity class {com.samir/com.samir.MainActivity-Red} does not exist.
```

Could any one suggest me the right approach

Comment: Are you trying to change the app's icon as it appears in the home page?

Comment: @GilMoshayof yes i am trying to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change your app icon after install. Instead, you could create a widget, request users to place it on their home screen and then change the image in that.

As for your error, `com.samir.MainActivity-Red` is an alias to `com.samir.MainActivity`, so try using `com.samir.MainActivity`

Answer (score 0):

It seems Android can't find an Activity to start, I guess because both aliases are disabled. Try to remove `android:enabled="false"` from your AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

From chainfire SuperSU tutorial. What he did there is he set one to default --> `android:enabled=true` for any one of the activity alias and this set as default.